# How to add an event to button with two classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

my button is defined:

```
<td>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" id="${machine.uid}">
<spring:message code="vending.generic.delete" />
</button>
</td>
```

I want to add an event handler to the button.

I tried this:

```
$(document).on("click",'.btn btn-danger',function(e){
....
}
```

Comment: @ImmerAllein That's completely wrong.. please update/delete your comment

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy oopss sory my bad

Comment: yes... is the same... the great cuestion is : 
$(".btn.btn-danger").click(function(e){....}

Comment: learn css first then come to jquery

Answer (score 2):

You can use another dot `.` without space to target element by multiple classes name:

```
$(document).on("click",'.btn.btn-danger',function(e){
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `.btn btn-danger` is an invalid selector, you have to merge by using a dot, so that the meaning becomes "Hey select all elements which contains class `btn` and class `btn-danger`"

Try,

```
$(document).on("click",'.btn.btn-danger',function(e){
....
}
```